# the function of "did"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, past-tense, verb-usage

I found a sentence in my "Preparation and Practice Exam TOEFL" book a sentence states *"Not until 1895 did Cornell University begin to offer a degree in ornithology"* . anyone can explain what the word "did" means in the sentence?
I mean, as we know "did" is a verb and should have a subject, but in that sentence I found that the subject is "Cornell University" and its verb is "begin". so why does "did" in the sentence exist? what for?

Answer (score 3):

Moving some kinds of 'adjunct' (modifying) phrases from their usual position to the front of a sentence triggers **subject-auxiliary inversion**, just as in questions. Most negative adjuncts, including those with *only*, do this:

> I will go.
>   → [<sub>inversion</sub>Will I] go?
>
> I will go only if I am paid.
>   → Only if I am paid [<sub>inversion</sub>will I] go.

If there is no auxiliary in the ordinary form of a sentence, "Do support" is required: the appropriate form of *do* is brought in as a 'dummy' to supply the auxiliary needed for inversion.

> Cornell offers a degree in ornithology.
>   → [<sub>inversion + do-support</sub>**Does** Cornell] offer a degree in ornithology?

This, too, occurs with fronted negative adjuncts:

> Cornell began to offer a degree in ornithology only in 1895.
>   → Only in 1895 [<sub>inversion + do-support</sub>**did** Cornell] begin to offer a degree in ornithology.